# Reading csv files

Tags: r, csv, import, dropbox

I'm having trouble reading .csv files into R, e.g.

```
df1991 <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/vwdw2tsmgiiuxfa/1991.csv")
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
more columns than column names

fishdata <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/pin16l691p6j4ll/fishdata.csv", row.names=NULL)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
more columns than column names
```

I've tried all sorts of variations of the header & row.names arguments.

I want to import the .csv files from dropbox for convenience, I have done so in the past without trouble. Any suggestions?

Comment: Both work fine for me without error.

Comment: As with @Thomas, both work fine for me. Have you tried with a clean session?

Comment: No actually, do I just restart Rstudio?

Comment: Works for me too ... maybe restart your computer, and also run 'rm(list=ls())' to remove all objects from your R workspace.  One last thing:  insert 'fill = TRUE' as an extra argument to read.csv and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Acceptable CSV, so perhaps your default settings. Locale (for comma interpreted as decimal)?

Could it be that the error message should be the other way around, that there are more column names than columns?

Grasping this straw, the first column of data might be interpreted as row labels, for which no column name might be required. It would then expect all the given column-names to relate to the columns of data that come after the first column. So, more column names than columns. Resolved by something like a 'row-names=1' import parameter.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It seems Rstudio itself is preventing me from reading data from online as it works just fine in the stand-alone R console.